# Objects of session and request

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, jakarta-ee, struts

In struts, where does the session object created & which class or method creates it? Likewise where does the request object created & which class or method invokes it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The request object is created inside your servlet container (tomcat/jetty/whatever).

The session is basically created by whoever calls getSession on [HttpServletRequest](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.2/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession(boolean)) first. Normally web frameworks do this only when someone actually declares they need the session. If you want to find out when this happens, I suggest you use "go to implementation" in your IDE and set a breakpoint and run the application (note there are two overloads)

Answer (score 1):

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletRequestAware;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;

public class MyAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware,ServletRequestAware
{
    Map<String,Object> session;
    HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {

        this.session = session;
    }

    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest hsr) {
       this.servletRequest=hsr;
    }

    public String execute()
    {
       return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Whenever this action is called setServletRequest is called first and then setSession().

The object of request & session are created by the web container you are using and passed to corresponding methods.

Answer (score 0):

In Struts an **ActionForm** instance can be stored in the **HttpSession** or in the **HttpServletRequest**.

It depends on the **scope** defined in the **action** tag inside the **struts-config.xml** file.

An **ActionForm** usually gets stored using the name defined in the **action-form** tag.